# avoid multiple cloned or duplicated div on button click and insertAfter the same last cloned div once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div and I want to duplicate it. I mean that I wanted the same div to be duplicated once. I have used such code for it.

```
$("#btnAddRules").click(function(){
    $(".div1_section").clone().insertAfter($(".div1_section"));
});
```

But, when click on the button again and again , it is adding multiple of the DIVs and I wanted only one div to be inserted after the last div.

```
<div class="col-md-8">
  <div class="row div1_section">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label>hey hey hey</label>
      <select class="form-control">
        <option>klklk</option>
        <option>huhuuh</option>
      </select>
      <br/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label>abc</label>
      <div class="input-group-currency">
        <span class="currency">pk</span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-currency" name="start" value="20'000" style="float:left">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Hope to hear from you, soon.

Thanks

Comment: `.last()` before `.clone()`

Comment: .last() is also adding the same multiple divs

Comment: yes @danip  thanks. I haven't used the .last() in the insertAfter(). After using it, fixes the problem. Thaks mate.

Comment: Glad to help U mate

Comment: Rephrase the question with current output and desired output with edge cases. Lets help others to help you. Cheers

Comment: rephrased. @MD.SahibBinMahboob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `last()` to target just the last element from the collection:

```js
$("#btnAddRules").click(function() {
  $(".div1_section").last().clone().insertAfter($(".div1_section").last());
});
```

```css
.div1_section {
  line-height:50px;
  margin:20px 0;
  padding:0 20px;
  background:tomato;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnAddRules">Add More Rules</button>
<div class="div1_section">Original</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the event listener after the first click like this:

```
var callback = function () {
    document.getElementById('btnAddRules').removeEventListener('click', callback);
    $(".div1_section").clone().insertAfter($(".div1_section"));
}   

document.getElementById('btnAddRules').addEventListener('click', callback);
```

Sorry for using vanilla JS and your jquery, I'm more used to write vanilla JS.

Answer (score 0):

Use `last()` to target just the last element from the collection and `after()` to put div after a div:

```js
$("#btnAddRules").click(function(){
   $(".div1_section").last().after($(".div1_section").last().clone());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div1_section" >
Hi this is testing
</div>
<button type="button" id="btnAddRules">
Add DIV
</button>
```